# Null grpc client channel

Tags: c++, null, grpc

Is it possible to create (c++) a grpc null channel that will simply fail all requests? Say if there is no address configured, I have two options (a) do not create channel and then 1000s times check whether channel is valid, (b) create a null channel and handle grpc errors in the normal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a channel to an unresolvable server URI, the channel will be what we call a "lame" channel.  It will fail all RPCs sent on the channel.

Comment: Thank you, say can I use  something like 'lame_proto://lame_host' or there is some established practice worth to follow?

Comment: There's no explicit API for creating a lame channel, but if you create one for which the target URI is unparseable, that should do it.  For example, you could use something like "http:?dangling-pct-%0".